# Similar paths to Compare

Tags: data, geoprocessing, mongodb, similarity

I want to implement a mechanism to compare similar / identical paths. For example, a person who makes the trip home - work every day, be able to detect these paths and create groups to compare different indicators (speed, altitude, ...).

For each trip taken by each driver is recorded with GPS coordinates along the path, so for every trip I have the coordinates along the route. Is there any algorithm to detect similarity between paths? I'm using a geospatial representation of MongoDB.

I am conducting a pre-processing on the gps data to eliminate error, consisting of round the coordinates to 3 decimal places approximately 111.32 m. Now I'm interested to know how I can consider that two paths are the same / similar to compare.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer could help you http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44312/2969